# Play sound with back button storyboard. Objective C

Tags: objective-c, audio, uinavigationcontroller, avaudioplayer

In Xcode's Storyboard mode. When you use a navigation controller the back button automatically appears.

Normally to play my sound I would call my task from a selector or action.

How can I play this sound with the back button? How can I code this because the back button automatically appears in a my view?

```
- (void)myTask {
NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/pop.wav"];
NSLog(@"Path to play: %@", resourcePath);
NSError* err;

//Initialize our player pointing to the path to our resource
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
          [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];

if( err ){
    //bail!
    NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
}
else{
    //set our delegate and begin playback
    player.delegate = self;
    [player play];
}
}
```

Regards

Blake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can play it in `- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated { // in here }`